# Disable DBT models using code or config (not commands)

Tags: dbt

Hello I have the following DBT project directory structure:

```
my_dbt_project/
  dbt_project.yml
  profiles.yml
  pyproject.toml
  requirements.txt
  <other config files here>
  models/
    abc/
      abc.yml
      abc.sql
    def/
      def.yml
      def.sql
    ghi/
      ghi.yml
      ghi.sql
    etc.
```

When I run `dbt <cmd> --profiles-dir=. --select models/`  where `<cmd>` is either compile, run or test, DBT runs the command on everything under `models/`.

In reality I have hundreds of "model subfolders" under `models/` and I am trying to disable just one of them (say, `def/`) so that if I were to run, say, `dbt run --profiles-dir=. --select models/`, it would run all the model transforms except everything defined under `models/def/*`.

Because of factors outside the scope of this question, changing the DBT commands is not an option for me. I need a way to configure something in a project file or under the `def/` directory (something in the code/configs) to tell DBT to skip over everything under `def/` and completely ignore/disable it.

Based on what I've presented above, how can I disable DBT for this specific model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `enabled` flag to disable models. In your example, you can add this to `dbt_project.yml` to disable all models in `def` folder:

```yaml
models:
  def:
    +enabled: false
```

More details in the documentation: https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/resource-configs/enabled